# Not able to install Hive on Apache Ambari with 2.5.1 repo version

Tags: hadoop, hive, ambari, bigdata

I have installed `Apache Ambari` on `centos` server with 64 GB Ram. I have installed many of tools on it(`Hbase`,`Hdfs`,`Zookeeper`,`Slider`,`Pig`,`Spoop`,`Mapreduce`,`Yarn`) but when I am trying to install `hive` then getting following error.

```
Error: Package: hive2_2_6_1_0_129-2.1.0.2.6.1.0-129.noarch (HDP-2.6)
           Requires: python-argparse
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Details error are here.

```
stderr: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HIVE/0.12.0.2.0/package/scripts/hcat_client.py", line 85, in <module>
    HCatClient().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 329, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HIVE/0.12.0.2.0/package/scripts/hcat_client.py", line 35, in install
    self.install_packages(env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 693, in install_packages
    retry_count=agent_stack_retry_count)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 155, in __init__
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 160, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 124, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/__init__.py", line 54, in action_install
    self.install_package(package_name, self.resource.use_repos, self.resource.skip_repos)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/yumrpm.py", line 51, in install_package
    self.checked_call_with_retries(cmd, sudo=True, logoutput=self.get_logoutput())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/__init__.py", line 86, in checked_call_with_retries
    return self._call_with_retries(cmd, is_checked=True, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/__init__.py", line 98, in _call_with_retries
    code, out = func(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 72, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 102, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep, timeout_kill_strategy=timeout_kill_strategy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 150, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 303, in _call
    raise ExecutionFailed(err_msg, code, out, err)
resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecutionFailed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hive2_2_6_1_0_129' returned 1. Error: Package: hive2_2_6_1_0_129-2.1.0.2.6.1.0-129.noarch (HDP-2.6)
           Requires: python-argparse
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
 stdout:
2017-06-24 12:27:40,199 - Stack Feature Version Info: stack_version=2.6, version=2.6.1.0-129, current_cluster_version=2.6.1.0-129 -> 2.6.1.0-129
2017-06-24 12:27:40,201 - Using hadoop conf dir: /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf
User Group mapping (user_group) is missing in the hostLevelParams
2017-06-24 12:27:40,203 - Group['hadoop'] {}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,206 - Group['users'] {}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,206 - User['hive'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,207 - User['zookeeper'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,209 - User['ams'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,210 - User['ambari-qa'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['users']}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,211 - User['tez'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['users']}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,212 - User['hdfs'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,213 - User['sqoop'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,214 - User['yarn'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,215 - User['mapred'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,216 - User['hbase'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,217 - User['hcat'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,219 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,221 - Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh ambari-qa /tmp/hadoop-ambari-qa,/tmp/hsperfdata_ambari-qa,/home/ambari-qa,/tmp/ambari-qa,/tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa'] {'not_if': '(test $(id -u ambari-qa) -gt 1000) || (false)'}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,229 - Skipping Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh ambari-qa /tmp/hadoop-ambari-qa,/tmp/hsperfdata_ambari-qa,/home/ambari-qa,/tmp/ambari-qa,/tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa'] due to not_if
2017-06-24 12:27:40,230 - Directory['/tmp/hbase-hbase'] {'owner': 'hbase', 'create_parents': True, 'mode': 0775, 'cd_access': 'a'}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,231 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,234 - Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh hbase /home/hbase,/tmp/hbase,/usr/bin/hbase,/var/log/hbase,/tmp/hbase-hbase'] {'not_if': '(test $(id -u hbase) -gt 1000) || (false)'}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,241 - Skipping Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh hbase /home/hbase,/tmp/hbase,/usr/bin/hbase,/var/log/hbase,/tmp/hbase-hbase'] due to not_if
2017-06-24 12:27:40,242 - Group['hdfs'] {}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,243 - User['hdfs'] {'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop', 'hdfs']}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,243 - FS Type: 
2017-06-24 12:27:40,244 - Directory['/etc/hadoop'] {'mode': 0755}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,276 - File['/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/hadoop-env.sh'] {'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'owner': 'hdfs', 'group': 'hadoop'}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,278 - Directory['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/hadoop_java_io_tmpdir'] {'owner': 'hdfs', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': 01777}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,301 - Initializing 2 repositories
2017-06-24 12:27:40,302 - Repository['HDP-2.6'] {'base_url': 'http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.6.1.0', 'action': ['create'], 'components': ['HDP', 'main'], 'repo_template': '[{{repo_id}}]\nname={{repo_id}}\n{% if mirror_list %}mirrorlist={{mirror_list}}{% else %}baseurl={{base_url}}{% endif %}\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0', 'repo_file_name': 'HDP', 'mirror_list': None}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,316 - File['/etc/yum.repos.d/HDP.repo'] {'content': '[HDP-2.6]\nname=HDP-2.6\nbaseurl=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.6.1.0\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0'}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,318 - Repository['HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21'] {'base_url': 'http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21/repos/centos6', 'action': ['create'], 'components': ['HDP-UTILS', 'main'], 'repo_template': '[{{repo_id}}]\nname={{repo_id}}\n{% if mirror_list %}mirrorlist={{mirror_list}}{% else %}baseurl={{base_url}}{% endif %}\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0', 'repo_file_name': 'HDP-UTILS', 'mirror_list': None}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,323 - File['/etc/yum.repos.d/HDP-UTILS.repo'] {'content': '[HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21]\nname=HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21\nbaseurl=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21/repos/centos6\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0'}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,324 - Package['unzip'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,436 - Skipping installation of existing package unzip
2017-06-24 12:27:40,437 - Package['curl'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,461 - Skipping installation of existing package curl
2017-06-24 12:27:40,462 - Package['hdp-select'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,481 - Skipping installation of existing package hdp-select
2017-06-24 12:27:40,774 - Using hadoop conf dir: /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf
2017-06-24 12:27:40,784 - call['ambari-python-wrap /usr/bin/hdp-select status hive-server2'] {'timeout': 20}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,826 - call returned (0, 'hive-server2 - 2.6.1.0-129')
2017-06-24 12:27:40,827 - Stack Feature Version Info: stack_version=2.6, version=2.6.1.0-129, current_cluster_version=2.6.1.0-129 -> 2.6.1.0-129
2017-06-24 12:27:40,844 - Version 2.6.1.0-129 was provided as effective cluster version.  Using package version 2_6_1_0_129
2017-06-24 12:27:40,847 - Package['hive_2_6_1_0_129'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,961 - Skipping installation of existing package hive_2_6_1_0_129
2017-06-24 12:27:40,963 - Version 2.6.1.0-129 was provided as effective cluster version.  Using package version 2_6_1_0_129
2017-06-24 12:27:40,965 - Package['hive_2_6_1_0_129-hcatalog'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2017-06-24 12:27:40,983 - Skipping installation of existing package hive_2_6_1_0_129-hcatalog
2017-06-24 12:27:40,984 - Version 2.6.1.0-129 was provided as effective cluster version.  Using package version 2_6_1_0_129
2017-06-24 12:27:40,985 - Package['hive_2_6_1_0_129-webhcat'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2017-06-24 12:27:41,000 - Skipping installation of existing package hive_2_6_1_0_129-webhcat
2017-06-24 12:27:41,000 - Version 2.6.1.0-129 was provided as effective cluster version.  Using package version 2_6_1_0_129
2017-06-24 12:27:41,002 - Package['hive2_2_6_1_0_129'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2017-06-24 12:27:41,016 - Installing package hive2_2_6_1_0_129 ('/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hive2_2_6_1_0_129')
2017-06-24 12:27:45,652 - Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hive2_2_6_1_0_129' returned 1. Error: Package: hive2_2_6_1_0_129-2.1.0.2.6.1.0-129.noarch (HDP-2.6)
           Requires: python-argparse
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
2017-06-24 12:27:45,652 - Failed to install package hive2_2_6_1_0_129. Executing '/usr/bin/yum clean metadata'
2017-06-24 12:27:45,939 - Retrying to install package hive2_2_6_1_0_129 after 30 seconds

Command failed after 1 tries
```

Please help me where I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to install argparse manually via easy_install or pip?

```
yum install python-setuptools
easy_install argparse
```

or

```
yum install python-setuptools
pip install argparse
```